# Java - Convert int to String without using any available API

Tags: java, string

I want to convert a primitive int to String with the following conditions :

Example

```
 input : int number = 474567;
```

convert into string with out using `String` class, Object class, no collection frame work.

Please let me know if this is possible with the above given condition. I am aware of all other methods i.e using collections and String class library.

Thanks in advance.

```
int digit = number;
int afterdivide = number;

String retValue = "";

while(afterdivide > 0) {
digit = afterdivide % 10;
afterdivide = afterdivide / 10;
if(digit == 0){
  retValue += "0";
}
else if(digit == 1){
  retValue += "1";
}
// Other numbers to follow
.
.
.
}
```

I tried something like this, but here i have created a String retValue and appending using '+' this will not satisfy my condition (String class used !!).
A clue was given to me to solve this. Clue : How do you think String class is written in java.

Comment: Yes possible, now you try some code and share it if stuck

Comment: I suspect your homework involves modulo and ASCII. Or you're not explaining how you'd like us to do your assignment for you.

Answer (score 9):

If no object methods should be used. This should work. Untested code but you get the idea.

```
int getlength(int x){
    while(x/10 != 0) length++;
    return length;
}
String convert(int x){
    char x_char = new char[getlength(x)];
    for(int i = x_char.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        x_char[i] = (char)(x % 10 + 48)//ASCII VALUE;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return new String(x_char);
}
```

Comment: +1 Seems to fit the constraint _"without using any available API"_

Comment: Why the `+ 48` on your `x_char[i] = (char)(x % 10 + 48)`?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine That is to convert an integer digit [0-9] to its character ASCII representation. If you look at the ASCII chart, the ASCII character '0' starts at 48, '1' at 49 and so on. http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes possible.

```
String result = ""+474567;
```

But that's a hack. Don't use it unless you need it.

Another good way is (If there is allow to Object class)

```
new Integer(474567).toString();
```

Comment: *Technically* That's using a `StringBuilder` and the `String` class ;) I suspect his homework is to figure out modulo and `char`

Comment: `new Integer(474567).toString();` <-- he can't use an "Object Class".

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways that I know of:

```
String result = Integer.toString(number);
```

or

```
String result = String.valueOf(number);
```

or, and this one is the one that you need to use (because you can't use an "Object Class"):

```
String result = number + "";
```

Comment: +1 I'm a particular fan of `String.valueOf()`. Seem most semantically correct :)

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, this will print it in reverse (it actually works for any base, not just 10):

```
public static void main(String...strings ){
    int num = 1234, base = 10;

    while(num >= 1){
        System.out.print(num%base);
        num /= base;
    }
}
```

---

**Output:** `4321`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is from toString method in Integer class.

```
public class Test
{
    final static char [] DigitTens = {
        '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
        '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
        '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
        '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6',
        '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7',
        '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8',
        '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9',
        } ; 

        final static char [] DigitOnes = { 
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        } ;

        final static char[] digits = {
            '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
            '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
            'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
            'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
            'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
            'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
            };

    final static int[] sizeTable = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999, 99999999, 999999999, Integer.MAX_VALUE };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int i = 1234;
            int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
            char[] buf = new char[size];
            getChars(i, size, buf);
            System.out.println(new String(buf, 0, size));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Requires positive x
    static int stringSize(int x) {
        for (int i = 0;; i++)
            if (x <= sizeTable[i])
                return i + 1;
    }

    static void getChars(int i, int index, char[] buf) {
        int q, r;
        int charPos = index;
        char sign = 0;

        if (i < 0) {
            sign = '-';
            i = -i;
        }

        // Generate two digits per iteration
        while (i >= 65536) {
            q = i / 100;
            // really: r = i - (q * 100);
            r = i - ((q << 6) + (q << 5) + (q << 2));
            i = q;
            buf[--charPos] = DigitOnes[r];
            buf[--charPos] = DigitTens[r];
        }

        // Fall thru to fast mode for smaller numbers
        // assert(i <= 65536, i);
        for (;;) {
            q = (i * 52429) >>> (16 + 3);
            r = i - ((q << 3) + (q << 1)); // r = i-(q*10) ...
            buf[--charPos] = digits[r];
            i = q;
            if (i == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (sign != 0) {
            buf[--charPos] = sign;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IntegertoString {
 
 public String s= "";
    // Method
    // Returning String from integer value
    public String tostring(int n)
    {
      while (n>0)
      {
          
          int num;
          num = n%10;
         
          s = ""+(num)+""+s;
          n= n/10;
     }
      return s;
    }
      
    // Method 2
    // main driver method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Input integer value
        int n = 12340321;
        
        IntegertoString inttostring = new IntegertoString();
         
        System.out.println(inttostring.tostring(n));
         }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
((Integer)number).toString()
```

use this method